# Exclude Subnets From Master List Using ipaddress module?

Tags: python, networking, google-cloud-platform, ip-address

I have a Python script that gets all of the network ranges we have deployed within the Google Cloud Platform. Whenever we create a new network, we need to ensure the network is unique and doesn't overlap with anything we've set up already. This is what I have so far:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account 
import ServiceAccountCredentials 
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('serviceaccount.json') 
compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials) cloudresman = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
projects = [] projectdicts = cloudresman.projects().list().execute() projectdicts = projectdicts.get('projects') 
for projectdict in projectdicts: 
    if "sandbox" not in projectdict['name']: 
        if projectdict['lifecycleState'] == "ACTIVE":             
            projects.append(projectdict['projectId']) 
        else: 
            print(projectdict['projectId'] + " is not active")

ipranges = [] 
for project in projects: 
    regiondicts = compute.regions().list(project=project).execute() regiondicts = 
    regiondicts.get('items') 
    for regiondict in regiondicts: 
        region = regiondict['name']     
        subnetworkdicts = compute.subnetworks().list(project=project,region=region).execute() 
        subnetworkdicts = subnetworkdicts.get('items') 
        if subnetworkdicts: 
            for subnetworkdict in subnetworkdicts:
                ipranges.append(IPv4Network(subnetworkdict['ipCidrRange'])) 
                if "secondaryIpRanges" in subnetworkdict:
                    secondaryranges = subnetworkdict['secondaryIpRanges'] 
                    for secondaryrange in secondaryranges: 
                        if secondaryrange['ipCidrRange'] not in ipranges:                 
                            ipranges.append(IPv4Network(secondaryrange['ipCidrRange']))
```

All of the subnets we use are within the 10.0.0.0/8 range.

But my question is: how can I exclude the list of subnets from a 'master list'?

I've tried the following:

```
masterranges = IPv4Network("10.0.0.0/8") 
for iprange in ipranges:     
    masterranges = masterranges.address_exclude(iprange)
```

However, that returns: 'generator' object has no attribute 'address_exclude'.

This makes sense because the 'generator' object is a list of subnets after the exclusion. I've also tried:

```
masterranges = IPv4Network("10.0.0.0/8") 
for iprange in ipranges:     
    masterranges = list(masterranges.address_exclude(iprange))
```

But of course, that then returns: 'list' object has no attribute 'address_exclude'.

The problem is that whenever I exclude one *iprange* from the master range, *address_exclude* produces a list of subnets, which I then need to iterate through with each *iprange*, which then, if successful, would produce a whole new list of subnets.

I'm struggling with the logic of how to make this work, so any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your approach -

```
masterranges = IPv4Network("10.0.0.0/8")       
for iprange in ipranges:        
     masterranges = list(masterranges.address_exclude(iprange))
```

Inside the *for* loop, ‘*masterranges*’ is being assigned as an object of *list* data type and on the very next iteration ‘*address_exclude*’ is being performed on it, which is creating a problem.

‘*address_exclude*’ works on objects of data type *ip_address*, not on objects of data type *list*.

I suggest you use another variable in line 3 to store the list, then run another loop to append those data out of the list into your masterranges.